# Why I can not execute the shutdown.sh in WinSCP?

Tags: linux, tomcat, terminal, server, winscp

I use WinSCP connect my remote server, and I `cd` into tomcat bin, and I want to execute the `shutdown.sh`.

[image]

But failed with the following message:

[image]

No matter I use:

```
./ shutdown.sh
```

Or

```
shutdown.sh
```

All will report the error.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"./ shutdown.sh"  there is a space between "./" and shutdown.sh

"./shutdown.sh" this is right

i don't know why like this.  I don't use WinSCP, try putty

Comment: O MY GOD  i‘m sorry  my english is bad !

you see that?  /.shutdown

must be  ./shutdown  !  maybe  your input is ./shutdown  but i don't know  why it change to /.shutdown  !   i'm sorry  i don't use WinSCP! 

i use putty